# Trouble with repeating form field buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, repeat

I'm fairly new to jquery and am having trouble correctly cloning this block of form elements with auto-incrementing id, for and name attributes. I am cloning the `div.repeatingSection` and ideally I want to clone only the remove button on the cloned sections.

So far I've managed get it working but the buttons themselves are cloned (even though I though `.clone(false)` was supposed to prevent that). I am also getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'` which is probably why it doesn't work correctly.

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>

<legend>Exp&eacute;rience professionnelle</legend>    
<div class="row repeatingSection"> 

<div class="large-10 small-12 columns panel inside">
    <div class="large-6 columns">

        <label for="poste_1">Poste :</label>
        <input type="text" name="poste_1" id="poste_1"/>

        <div class="row">  
            <div class="large-6 columns">    
                <label for="de_1">De :</label>
                <input type="date" name="de_1" id="de_1" class="small"/>  
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">    
                <label for="a_1">A :</label>
                <input type="date" name="a_1" id="a_1" class="small"/>  
            </div>
        </div>

        <label for="contrat_1">Contrat :</label>
        <select name="contrat_1" ID="contrat_1" class="small">
        <option></option>
        <option value='CDI'>CDI</option>
        <option value='CDD'>CDD</option>
        <option value='stagiaire'>Stagiaire</option>
        <option value='saisonnier'>Saisonnier</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <label for="description_1"> Description: </label>
        <textarea id="description_1" name="description_1" class="lrg-txtarea"></textarea>
    </div>
</div><!-- end repeatingSection -->

<div class="large-2 small-12 columns">
    <button class="cloneButton small secondary radius indent">Ajouter +</button>
    <button class="removeButton small secondary radius indent">Enlever -</button>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery('.cloneButton').click(function(event){

event.preventDefault();

var currentCount =  jQuery('.repeatingSection').length;
var newCount = currentCount+1;
var lastRepeatingGroup = jQuery('.repeatingSection').last();
var newSection = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(false);

newSection.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
newSection.find("input").each(function (index, input) {
    input.id = input.id.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
    input.name = input.name.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
});
newSection.find("label").each(function (index, label) {
    var l = jQuery(label);
    l.attr('for', l.attr('for').replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount));
});
return false;
});

jQuery('.removeButton').live('click', function(){

    jQuery(this).closest('div.repeatingSection').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Any help would be ever so much appreciated.
Here is a js a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/engRg/

Comment: Depending which jq version you are using (info not provided by your jsfiddle!!!), live() has been removed (jq 1.9), use .on() delegation syntax

Comment: I believe its 1.10.2 (it has to work with Wordpress 3.6). Well that explains the error then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jq 1.9, use `.on()` to delegate event: {or you could use `.delegate()` method}

```
jQuery(document.body).on('click','.removeButton', function(){...});
```

Comment: Much better. Thanks! How could I only clone the remove button and not the add button on the additional fields?

Comment: To remove specific element form a clone: `lastRepeatingGroup.clone(false).find('.cloneButton').remove().end();`  That's said, as you seems to just want to clone one element, then clone it directly, not its parent container.

Comment: No, I do want to clone all the elements in the div not just the button.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. If I fill out the section and then hit the add button, I'm duplicating the form fields and their content. Rather than an empty form.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i believe ur task has been done already check out this fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/tfFLt/

```
$("button.clone").live("click", function(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
        .appendTo("body")
        .attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex)
        .find("*").each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 3) {
                this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
            }
    });
    cloneIndex++;
});
```

Comment: It does look tidier. My only problem is that I understand the one I'm using and not the one you proposed and I need to increment the `name` and `for` attributes as well. I actually wanted to clone the remove button but not the add button. Thanks though, I'll bookmark it for when I understand it better.